# Share segments to all collaborators in views from all properties

Tags: google-analytics

I have 20+ properties and I need to share the same set of 10+ segments to all the properties in a way any collaborator can see it in any view from any property.

From the "Segment availability":

[image]

I know that I can see the same segment in any view (1st option), but can't the collaborators won't see it.
It is also possible to make it available for all Collaborators in "this" View (3rd option), but it won't accessible in other views.

It seems to me it is missing a 4th option "Collaborators and I can apply Segment in any View". As far as I can see, the only way to achieve it is to copy the segments via "asset sharing" in each view and make it available for all collaborators one by one, which is a tedious task and bad for future changes.

Is there any other way to share multiple segments to all collaborators in multiple/all views?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "bundle" of segments and share it with the collaborators.

1. Go to the *Audience > Overview report* in one of
   the Views that has the segments available.
2. Click *+Add Segment* at the top of the report, as if to apply a segment.
3. When the segment options open up, click the *Share segments* button (2nd button to
   the right of the red *+NEW SEGMENT* button).
4. It will take you to a table with all your segments, where you can select a check box for which segments you want to share. Select all the applicable segments.
5. Click the red *Share* button at the top of the table. A grey model will open titled *Select a method for sharing [object Object]*.
6. Choose the first option: *Share template link* and click the grey Share button at the bottom of the modal.
7. Another modal will appear with a shareable link.
8. Share this link with the collaborators.

The collaborators can then copy/paste the link into their browser address bar, and GA will give them the option to add the segments to any View or to select a particular View to add them to.